# WSO2IS-5.7.0 OIDC SSO logout without id_token_hint

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am working with OIDC and WSo2IS-5.7.0. I Want to implement rp initiated global logout (I want to terminate the session from RP and as well as OP or WSO2 in my case.) When user clicks on logout button, I am redirecting the user to this URL :

```
https://myserver:9443/oidc/logout?id_token_hint=<idtoken>&post_logout_redirect_uri=https://myotherserver.com/myapp/index
```

It is working fine and user is redirected to login page of wso2. My client consider it not secure and want to do the same without being send id_token to front end. Is it possible with wso2is-5.7.0?

If yes, how?

If no, isn't it insecure that we send id token to FE? anyone can use it to make API call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. In WSO2 implementation we use the id_token_hint to extract the client_id  from the id_token (sent as the id_token_hint). This is necessary to retrieve the service provider information for which the id_token was issued to.

Otherwise we don't have a way to validate whether the value sent in post_logout_redirect_uri is a registered callback for the service provider.

So if we omit the id_token_hint, we cannot validate the post_logout_redirect_uri sent which will open up another security hole allowing redirection to untrusted uris.

Comment: What kind of security hole can there be in the exit action?)) And how can a simple transition be considered a security hole? Moreover, If I correctly understand in the spec https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html
it says that if id_token_hint is not provided, then the OP must issue a confirmation request. Those. request without id_token_hint should be considered valid? right?